# Incrementando checkbox em list

Tags: javascript, html

Bom, estou criando uma aplicação de "megasena", estou tentando gerar junto dos meus jogos, um checkbox, no momento pesquisei bastante e não encontro soluções paraimplementar isso.

função que gera minha lista dentro da ul:

```
function renderSavedGames(){
var divSavedGames = document.querySelector('#megasena-saved-games');
divSavedGames.innerHTML = '';

if (state.savedGames.length === 0) {
    divSavedGames.innerHTML = '<p>Nenhum jogo salvo</p>';
} else {
    var ulSavedGames = document.createElement('ul');

    for (var i = 0; i < state.savedGames.length; i++){
        var currentGame = state.savedGames[i];
        var liGame = document.createElement('li');
        liGame.classList.add('savedGames');
        liGame.textContent = currentGame.join('-');
        
        ulSavedGames.appendChild(liGame);
    }
    divSavedGames.appendChild(ulSavedGames);
}
```

}

já tentei concatenar com uma variável contendo o elemento do checkbox, mas resulta no erro: HTMLUnknownElement.

alguem poderia me da uma luz sobre como posso implementar os checkbox junto das listas que são apresentada dentro dessa função?

como estou tentando:

```
for (var i = 0; i < state.savedGames.length; i++){
        var currentGame = state.savedGames[i];
        var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        var liGame = document.createElement('li');
        liGame.classList.add('savedGames');
        liGame.textContent = x + currentGame.join('-');
        
        ulSavedGames.appendChild(liGame);
    }
```

[erro apresentado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTqgm.png)

o esperado seria:

[editei no html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3QM5.png)

Comment: Você poderia editar a pergunta, colocando um print da forma esperada e como fica?

Comment: Peço desculpas, não utilizo o stackoverlow, nunca utilizei na realidade.

Comment: o erro ocorre nessa linha `liGame.textContent = x + currentGame.join('-');` isso não é uma tag html e por isso a mensagem.

Comment: Não precisava da imagem já que é intuitivo que é um `checkbox` e o erro que é apresentado não deveria aparecer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que resultou nessa mensagem **HTMLUnknownElement** foi que o navegador não reconhece  essa tag *html* , nessa ocasião o navegador se depara com uma tag  desconhecida pode ser também que não é suportada.

Nesse trecho que ocasionou essa mensagem:

```
liGame.textContent = x + currentGame.join('-');
```

A maneira apropriada de escrever essa parte é incluir o elemento `input` e o número isolados do elemento `li`

```
    function renderSavedGames(){
       ... código original mantido ...
        for (var i = 0; i < state.savedGames.length; i++) {
          var currentGame = state.savedGames[i];

          // Criado o elemento do tipo checkbox
          var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
          checkbox.type = "checkbox";
          checkbox.name = "game-" + i;
          checkbox.value = currentGame.join("-");

          // Cria o li incluindo input"
          var liGame = document.createElement('li');
          liGame.classList.add('savedGames');
          liGame.htmlFor = checkbox.name; // htmlFor

        
         liGame.appendChild(checkbox);
         liGame.textContent = currentGame.join("-");

         ulSavedGames.appendChild(liGame);
    }

        divSavedGames.appendChild(ulSavedGames);
   }
 }
```

- [**htmlFor**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element)

Associa rótulos `label` ao contexto do `input` , serve para alterna o estado do checkbox.

Comment: Deu certo amigão, desculpa a demora para responder. Só que os checkbox ficaram após os jogos e não antes deles.

Comment: Creio que ao trocar a posição possa resolver, abaixo de `liGame.htmlFor` aconteceu  a troca